# How to optimize The Table inserted A record that cause Other Tables which directly count( or recurse count) The Tables record nums update in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot, database-design

Here is a model, We have

Academy--Major--Class--Student

A student only belong to A class

A class only belong to A major

A major only belong to A academy

```java
class Academy {
    String name;
    Integer personCount;
}

class Major {
    String name;
    Integer academyId;
    Integer personCount;
}

class _Class {
    String name;
    Integer majorId;
    Integer personCount;
}

class Student {
    Long id;
    String name;
    Integer academyId;
    Integer majorId;
    Integer _classId;
}
```

so, for each entity , there is a table map to it
now, we insert a record to Table `student`

when the record has saved, the Table `class` has to update its record (the student belong), set person_count = person_count + 1

after it has done, the Table `major` also has to update its record (the updated record belong), set person_count = person_count + 1

also, The table `academy` still has to do update like `major` and `class`

is there a better sloution to reduce the database write times? or a better table structure?

I'm still think of it, it do pressed the database of write

the limit of student records will below 100,000.

but in a specific time it will do high frequent inserts

I expected a fast response solution

Comment: You must store referencing identifier for the closest table in adjacency chain only. I.e. store only `Integer _classId;` in Student, and remove `Integer academyId;` and `Integer majorId;`. You shouldn't store `personCount` at all, count the amount of persons with according query when you need in it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your advice is a good solution to solve the storage pressure of the database.       But also, this structure will do many link between `academy`,`major`,`class`,`student` when i try to query the personCount of a academy.       Should I keep the column of `_classId`,`academyId`,`majorId` in Table `student` to reduce the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan A:  Use `TRIGGER ... ON INSERT ...`

Plan B:  Explicitly write `UPDATEs` to bump the counters.

Plan C:  Encapsulate Plan B into Stored Procedures.

Plan D:  Don't keep the counts in the tables, but recompute them when needed.  (This is the purist way -- "thou shalt not have redundant info".)  For a thousand students, I doubt if there is much "pressure".  For a million students, performance is likely to be poor.  In that case, what you have (tables with `personCount`) is essentially [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Comment: it's a good idea.   So I think there is a middle ground, add a `TRIGGER` on Table `student` where there have `INSERT` to `UPDATE` only on `personCount` of the Table `course`.    But for Table `academy`,`major`,   do not keep the `personCount` but to select Table `course` ( Table course have the field 'academy_id`, 'major_id`,'`personCount` ).         Is it feasible for 100,000 records?

Comment: @Ice_Wift - 100K rows may be "fast enough"; you will have to try it.  (There are too many unknown factors for me to predict.)